# Basic plotting in R with date choosing specific values

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe of air pollution data : each country has for each day, a value for each measure (co,pm10...)

I would like to make a graphic per country and for each Specie that shows its evolution on a given period (from 6/2019 to 06/2020) but I don't know how as there are many countries

Here are the first lines of the dataframe :

```
    Date   Country Specie median
1   2014-12-29  AT  co    0.1
2   2014-12-29  AT  no2   15.780000000000001
3   2014-12-29  AT  pm10  20.8
4   2014-12-29  AT  pm25  69.5
5   2014-12-29  AT  so2   2.0
6   2014-12-29  AU  co    2.3333333333333335
7   2014-12-29  AU  neph  6.333333333333333
8   2014-12-29  AU  no2   4.314285714285714
9   2014-12-29  AU  o3     13.171428571428569
10  2014-12-29  AU  pm10    11.666666666666666
11  2014-12-29  AU  pm25    18.22222222222222
12  2014-12-29  AU  so2     3.3166666666666664
13  2014-12-29  BE  co     0.1
14  2014-12-29  BE  no2    19.416666666666668
15  2014-12-29  BE  o3  5.666666666666667
```

Comment: Is`Specie` the air monitor? Are these the same for each country or different? Maybe show a few readings from 1 or 2 more countries as well.

Comment: @ToddBurus Yes, Specie is the air monitor and they are pretty much the same except for a few countries. I added a few rows so it's clearer